# to add dropdown in a table dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a table which i cant fill up with data dynamically ... it only  tends to show the last table cell the rest rows are empty.The dropdowndownlist seems to popuate in the right way though.

```
DataTable dtt1 = (DataTable)Session["dbasecolumns"];
    int l = dtt1.Columns.Count;
    string[] sqlcolumn = new string[l];


    ***for (int j = 0; j < dtt1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        sqlcolumn[j] = dtt1.Columns[j].ColumnName;
    }
    Session["excel"] = sqlcolumn;***


DropDownList drd = new DropDownList();
    foreach (String colname in sqlcolumn)
    {

        drd.Items.Add(colname);
    }

    Table mytable = new Table();
    mytable.Visible = true;

    for (int rowctr = 0; rowctr < sqlcolumn.Length; rowctr++)
    {
        TableRow myrow = new TableRow();
        mytable.Rows.Add(myrow);


        for (int cellctr = 0; cellctr < 1; cellctr++)
        {
            TableCell mycell = new TableCell();
            mycell.Controls.Add(drd);
            myrow.Cells.Add(mycell);
        }
      ***mytable.Rows.Add(myrow);***
     }

    Panel1.Controls.Add(mytable);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You really should give 'l' a better variable name, for a few moments I thought that was '1'. Just for clarity...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DataTable dtt1 = (DataTable)Session["dbasecolumns"];
int l = dtt1.Columns.Count;
string[] sqlcolumn = new string[l];
DropDownList drd = new DropDownList();
foreach (String colname in sqlcolumn)
{
    drd.Items.Add(colname);
}
```

You are iterating over `sqlcolumn` but your `sqlcolumn` is empty. It does not have any values to fill up your `DropDownList`. Here you have defined your string `array` of a particular length but it does not contains any value. (Hope I am on right direction as I can see only this much of your code).

You can directly fill your `DropDownList` from a datatable.

```
DataTable dtt1 = (DataTable)Session["dbasecolumns"];   

DropDownList drd = new DropDownList();
for (int i = 0; dtt1 .Rows.Count > i; i++)
{
    dhgdh.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["dbasecolumns"].ToString());
}
```

This will work

```
for (int rowctr = 0; rowctr <= sqlcolumn.Length; rowctr++)
{
    TableRow myrow = new TableRow();
    mytable.Rows.Add(myrow);

    // for (int cellctr = 0; cellctr <= 1; cellctr++)
    //{
    DropDownList drd = new DropDownList();
    foreach (String colname in sqlcolumn)
    {
        drd.Items.Add(colname);
    }

    TableCell mycell = new TableCell();
    mycell.Controls.Add(drd);
    myrow.Cells.Add(mycell);
    //}
    mytable.Rows.Add(myrow);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mr Suraj.I have added the code for populating the sqlcolumn.I checked the Page Source after running the code ....
`<table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><select name="ctl03"><option value="ID">ID</option><option value="Name">Name</option><option value="Login_Id">Login_Id</option>
<option value="Email_Id">Email_Id</option><option value="Designation">Designation</option><optionvalue="Address">Address</option></select></td></tr></table>`
only the last row of the table is filled with the control.The rest td are empty

Comment: @rawatdeepesh  i got an solution although it's not a clean one bu check my answer i have edited it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Suraj , It worked...Please accept my answer  too if you feel its right by clicking the tick .

Answer (score 2):

i added a table with two columns.Each column has a `dropdownlist` with the `listitems` from a `SQL` database and an `Excel` file.

```
 for (int rowctr = 0; rowctr <= sqlcolumn.Length; rowctr++)
    {
          mycell = new TableCell();
        TableCell mycell1 = new TableCell();

         for (int cellctr = 0; cellctr < 1; cellctr++)
         {
            DropDownList drd = new DropDownList();
            DropDownList drd1 = new DropDownList();
            foreach (String colname in sqlcolumn)
            {
                drd.Items.Add(colname);                    
            }

            foreach (string colnames in excel)
            {
                drd1.Items.Add(colnames);
            }                
            TableRow myrow = new TableRow();           

            mycell.Controls.Add(drd);
            mycell1.Controls.Add(drd1);            
            myrow.Cells.Add(mycell);
            myrow.Cells.Add(mycell1);
            mytable.Rows.Add(myrow);
}
Panel1.Controls.Add(mytable);
```